# Validation not working in HTML5 form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form that needs to have two buttons which determine the fundamental action of the form. So I set up two buttons like this;

```
    $('#get-quote').click(function() {
    $("#quote-form").attr("action", "mail.php?action=quote");
    $('#quote-form').submit();
});

$('#get-bind').click(function() {
    $("#quote-form").attr("action", "mail.php?action=bind");
    $('#quote-form').submit();
});
```

My problem is that the HTML validation on required fields is skipped, ie the fields can be blank and the form is still submitted. I see the validation tips "This field is required" flash up briefly but the form is submitted all the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your validation code?

Comment: What he wants to say is HTML attribute `required`, when it is set on the input. When you submit the form and not filling the input, it will show you warning and will not post the form. But when you submit it with JS, it will be ignored. Look at this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h54qzuvL/), try to press enter in the input and then click on the button and see the difference.

Comment: OK, I understand. I am struggling as how to present two buttons which is the easiest way to give this choice to the user.

I may have to give them a radio set and one submit button.

Comment: @Wojtek T; I'm not doing explicit vailidation, I'm relying on HTML5 for the `required` fields.